# How to change the content of the paragraph tag when button is clicked with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want something like this 
I love Pizza

I love Beans

I love Tacos

I love Fish

I love Chicken

and here is my code it is just printing I love chicken:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick="displayFood()">Show Food</button>
    <p id="food"></p>


 <script>
    function displayFood() {
       var text; 
       var food = ["Pizza", "Beans", "Tacos", "Fish", "Chicken"];
       var i;
       for(i = 0; i <food.length;i++) {
           text = "I love " + food[i] + "<br>";
           document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = text;


       }

       }

</script>
```

Comment: `=` Assigning to `innerHTML` like that will overwrite whatever was in it before, what were you expecting?

Comment: can you give the changed code

Comment: You can add the new value into previous html by changing the `document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = text;` into `document.getElementById("food").innerHTML += text;`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like that

```js
function displayFood() {
  var food = ["Pizza", "Beans", "Tacos", "Fish", "Chicken"];
  var text = '';
  food.forEach(function(el){
   document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = text+= 'I love ' + el + '</br>';
  });

}

//document.querySelector('.show').addEventListener('click', displayFood);
```

```html
<button class="show" onClick="displayFood()">Show Food</button>
<p id="food"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a little bit of modification will do.

You need to assign an initial value to `text` like this `var text = ""` (an empty string).

Then you need to move `document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = text;`
outside of the loop so you don't overwrite it each time (or you can use `+=` instead of `=` and keep it inside of loop).

Last thing, you can move declaration of `i` to the loop header and I would recommend using `let` and `const` keywords to declare variables instead of `var`.

```js
function displayFood() {
    let text = ""; // give it an initial value
    const food = ["Pizza", "Beans", "Tacos", "Fish", "Chicken"];
    for(let i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
        text += "I love " + food[i] + "<br>";
    }
    // move the assignment outside of loop
    document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayFood()">Show Food</button>
<p id="food"></p>
```

And you don't even need an explicit loop to achieve this task. All you need is `Array.prototype.reduce` and then you can do something like this.

```js
function displayFood() {
  const food = ["Pizza", "Beans", "Tacos", "Fish", "Chicken"];
  document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = food.reduce((acc, v) => acc + "I love " + v + "<br>", "");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayFood()">Show Food</button>
<p id="food"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick="displayFood()">Show Food</button>
    <p id="food"></p>


 <script>
     
    function displayFood() {
        
           var text = ""; //asign empty string to text
           var food = ["Pizza", "Beans", "Tacos", "Fish", "Chicken"];
           var i;
           for(i = 0; i <food.length;i++) {
               text += "I love " + food[i] + "<br>";
               document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = text;

           }

       }
       /* This will output as follows: 
       
       I love Pizza
       I love Beans
       I love Tacos
       I love Fish
       I love Chicken
       
       */

</script>
```

Here is the correct code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick="displayFood()">Show Food</button>
    <p id="food"></p>


 <script>
     
    function displayFood() {
        
           var text = ""; //asign empty string to text
           var food = ["Pizza", "Beans", "Tacos", "Fish", "Chicken"];
           var i;
           for(i = 0; i <food.length;i++) {
               text += "I love " + food[i] + "<br>";
               document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = text;

           }

       }

</script>
```